# Serious flaw with figure element and margins/paddings. Any clues?

Tags: css, html

It seems there is a bug with the html5 `figure` element. I've researched  here on SO and all the answers I find seem to point to the `img` element being the culprit. But that is not the case. At least for me. To test this I tried the following.

I made this as simple as possible for demo purposes.

```
<figure>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```

If I were to put that on my page, that would generate extra margins and padding. Now most answers on SO state that the image is the problem and to use `display:block` or vertical align to fix this. So to prove (to myself) that I wasn't going crazy, I did this again without a image in it.

```
<figure>&nbsp;</figure>
```

The result? Extra margins and padding are still being added. So in my opinion, `figure` is the issue. I tried in my CSS 0 margin and 0 padding and margin is still be added to `figure` element. I would like to use this more in my sites but can't until I figure out this dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like webkit adds proprietary margins to the figure element:

```
figure {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

I was able to solve the problem by setting the webkit margins to 0:

```
figure {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing the result: https://jsfiddle.net/ae5yopmu/